# change provider for sitemappath control programmatically

Tags: asp.net, sitemap

in web.config file there is 2 provider for sitemappath control

```
 <siteMap defaultProvider="RouteBaseSitemapProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="RouteBaseSitemapProvider" type="AmlakAlmamlakLib.RouteBaseSitemapProvider" siteMapFile="Web.sitemap"/>
        <add name="RouteBaseSitemapProvider1" type="AmlakAlmamlakLib.RouteBaseSitemapProvider"  siteMapFile="Web - Copy.sitemap"/>
      </providers>
    </siteMap>
```

in aspx file there is sitemappath control

```
<asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMap1" runat="server"/>
```

**question**:

sitemap path control default use **RouteBaseSitemapProvider** this provider. I want to change provider pragmatically in code behind file.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the provider this way in code behind file:

```
SiteMap1.SiteMapProvider = "RouteBaseSitemapProvider1";
```